# ClassCastException while adding printer name in PrintRequestAttributeSet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, networking, printing

I am getting following exception while executing my printer program. Is there any other way to specify network printer that is not configured in system.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException   at
>   javax.print.attribute.AttributeSetUtilities.verifyAttributeValue(AttributeSetUtilities.java:552)
>     at
>   javax.print.attribute.HashAttributeSet.add(HashAttributeSet.java:304)
>     at com.printing.PrintingService.main(PrintingService.java:118)

**Code**

```
public static void main(String [] a) throws FileNotFoundException, PrintException {
    String text = " My first Printer Program";

    InputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes());
    if (fis == null) 
    { 
        System.out.print("No File");
        return; 
    } 
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new  HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

    PrintService[] service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, aset);
    aset.add(new PrinterName("ipp://abcd.com/ipp/ITDepartment-HP4050", null)); ///// throwing exception on this line :ClassCastException

    if (service != null){
        System.out.println("Printer: " + service[0].getName());

        DocPrintJob job = service[0].createPrintJob();
        try{
            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis,flavor,null);
            job.print(doc,aset);
            fis.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you are adding PrinterName attribute to AttributeSetUtilities. The add() method only objects to type Attribute or subclasses of same

Comment: then how can I add a printer to PrintRequestAttributeSet, Any other way to add printername ?

Comment: you should add PrinterName to HashPrintServiceAttributeSet.